# Webkit does not update CSS styles with sibling and attribute selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I'm working on a form in .NET and am using the standard field validators. What I want is to make the input field change background color if the user clicks the "submit" button without filling in the mandatory field (the `requiredfieldvalidator` tag becomes visible).

I've done this by having a `requiredfieldvalidator` just before the input field. When the user clicks the "submit" button, the validator changes from `display:none` to `display:inline`. But what I'm interested in is setting a different background color on the input field, so I did something like this:

### CSS

```
.error[style*="inline"] + input { background-color: #e8bab2; }
```

### HTML

```
<span  class="error" style="display:none;"></span>
<input type="text">
<input type="button" id="sendme" value="Send" />
```

### JS (the validator handles this part)

```
$(function() {
    $("#sendme").click(function() {
        $(".error").css("display","inline");
    });
});
```

The problem is that the field will light up as red in Firefox when I click the button but in Webkit (Chrome 19/Safari 5.1) the input field won't change background color until I click the input field.

I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhbUH/), compare the behavior between Firefox and Webkit browsers.

(note: all the JS logic is deleted to make it more "clean")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens! Please check this out:

[image: Chrome]

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Does it really become red the first time you click "Send" and NOT clicking inside the input field?

Comment: I am using `19.0.1084.56 m`, do one thing. Click on the `input`, then click on `Send` and then again click on the `input`. Hope it works then! :P

Comment: Yes I now it works if I click the input again. But that's not good enough. Compare to Firefox and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Yeah I saw that... May be it needs a repainting, which is done in Chrome by clicking on the input. Okay, do one thing. On the `click` function of the `Send` button, add this code: `$('input').focus();`. It might help! :)

Comment: Actually, it did :) But i rotated the elements 0 degrees instead. By using the .NET isValid boolean i could do lite this:

if (!isValid) {
 $('.error[style*="inline"] + input').each(function() {
  this.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotateZ(0deg)';
 });
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#sendme").click(function() {  
        $(".error").css("display","inline");  
        $('.error[style*="inline"] + input').css("background-color","#e8bab2");  
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fhbUH/3/

Comment: See my answer to kuh-chan. The logic for changing state of the validator tag is handled by the asp.net validator. So this kind of soulution, even though your answer is appreciated, would require to much work right now.

Comment: And what if you use a wrapper around the input field?
Demo:  
http://jsfiddle.net/fhbUH/4/

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers are failing - not only the one you tested. If I were you I'd change the class of the `input` - jQuery has methods for this. (`addclass`,`removeclass`)

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But that would include a lot of code rewriting since the logic behind showing/hiding the validator tag is done by the asp:requiredfield-validator. And the validator (as sucky as it might be) handles some other logic as well including postbacks and so on.